# Can I read multiline input() during list comprehension?

Tags: list-comprehension

This is just for my own curiosity about the language.

I have this working code:

```
for i in range(n):
    name, grade = input(), int(input())
    students += [[name, grade]]
```

Usually with a for loop that's constructing a list, I'm able to write a list comprehension, so I'm curious whether I can in this case.

I've tried a couple of experiments already, both were unsuccessful.

`students = [[[name, grade]] for name in input() for grade in input() for i in range(n)]`

but I get EOFerror. So maybe it is possible and there's some other error in my code, or maybe it's not at that error is caused by whatever strangeness occurs when I try this.

I also tried:

`students = [[[name, grade]] for name, grade in zip(input(), int(input())) for i in range(n)]`

Which raises an error informing me the second argument of zip must be iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can,

```
students=[[input(), input()] for i in range(3)]
```